# Is there a way to get the position of the curson inside a text field using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component with a text field and a separate React popover component. The text field is the TextAreaAutosize component from the [textarea autosize library](https://github.com/Andarist/react-textarea-autosize#readme). The popover only opens if a certain keyword is entered and closes if another key which is not the keyword is pressed. I have the logic for showing and hiding the popver but it always opens at a fixed position. I have been trying to get it to display relative to the position(coordinates) of the cursor inside the text field. Is there a way to do this in React?

Comment: You mean not just the position (index) of the cursor in the text, but the position (coordinates) of the cursor on the screen?

Comment: @Bergi Yes. I should update my question.

Comment: Try using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: @Bergi Didn't work. item(1) is undefined on the TextArea DOM element. To use the range, the text inside the text field needs to be a DOM element, which it is not. Is there a way to access that text as a DOM element?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the coordinates or the cursor inside the input filed or any other element using

```
document.querySelector(element).addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  console.log(event);
});
```

The `event` object that will be logged in your console has more properties than you need but feel free to use any of them, but what you need to use is `layerY` and `layerX` that will give you the cursor coordinates relative to the input filed

```
console.log(event.layerX, event.layerY);
```

Working example:

```js
const el = (e) => document.querySelector(e);
el('#tex').addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  el('#tooltip').style.transform = `translate3d(${e.layerX}px, ${e.layerY}px, 0)`;
})
```

```css
.textarea-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
  display: none;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
}

.textarea-container:hover span {
  display: inline;
}

.textarea-container textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea-container">
  <span id="tooltip" class="tooltip">Message</span>
  <textarea id="tex" placeholder="your text..."></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a small warning, never use an element position and position it in real time using `left` and `top` because it's proven to make the rendering slower, always use transform.